# 9 graph plot in one x and y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to draw this graph in R (`ggplot2`)?

Format for desired result:

[image: Format for desired result]

```
x <- c(0.383358433,0.814784747,0.124074272,0.115872248)
y <- c(0.49729405,0.84456263,0.793699842,0.911446588)
z <- qplot(x,y,geom = "line")
z
x1 <- c(0.383358433,0.814784747,0.124074272,0.115872248)
y1 <- c(0.49729405,0.84456263,0.793699842,0.911446588)
z1 <- qplot(x1,y1,geom = "line")
z1
x2 <- c(0.383358433,0.814784747,0.124074272,0.115872248)
y2 <- c(0.49729405,0.84456263,0.793699842,0.911446588)
z2 <- qplot(x2,y2,geom = "line")
z2
x3 <- c(0.383358433,0.814784747,0.124074272,0.115872248)
y3 <- c(0.49729405,0.84456263,0.793699842,0.911446588)
z3 <- qplot(x3,y3,geom = "line")
z3
x4 <- c(0.383358433,0.814784747,0.124074272,0.115872248)
y4 <- c(0.49729405,0.84456263,0.793699842,0.911446588)
z4 <- qplot(x4,y4,geom = "line")
z4
x5 <- c(0.383358433,0.814784747,0.124074272,0.115872248)
y5 <- c(0.49729405,0.84456263,0.793699842,0.911446588)
z5 <- qplot(x,y,geom = "line")
z5
require(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(z,z1,z2,z3,z4,z5)
```

I tried with `ggplot` but I couldn't get the desired result.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Do spend some time reading [how to post a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), use `dput(DF)` to post your sample data and also `?facet_wrap`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, don't use caps locks.

Comment: Please, have a look at `facet_wrap()` from the `ggplot2` package.

Comment: please help me how to incorporate in my code

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the help page of `?grid.arrange`

```
plotList = list(z,z1,z2,z3,z4,z5)
arrangedPlot = marrangeGrob(plotList,nrow=3,ncol=3)
ggsave("multipage.png", arrangedPlot,device="png")
```

**Plot:**

[image]

Comment: click on Format for desired result:    i want that format

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments, have a look at  `?facet_wrap`. This will have output as close to what you expect, for any further "enhancements" you will have to tinker with grobs or maybe if you are lucky @baptiste might stumble upon this